# ajax selective not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

(function () {$('.KisiSilici').click( function () {
 does not working .click, .on, .live, is my try but not work. Thanks for your help.

maybe it was because I fill the table with ajax

```js
    $(document).ready(function Kisilertabs() {
                 $(function () {
                     $("#tabs").tabs();
                 });
                 var id = @Model.ID.ToString()
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '@Url.Action("Kisiler", "Cihazlar")',
                     type: "get",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     data: { data: id },
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (data) {
                         var row = "<tr><th width='70'>S. No</th><th width='220'> Adı </th><th width='220'>Soyadı</th><th>Sicil No</th><hr/></tr>";
                         $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                             row += "<tr id='" + item.ID + "'><td>" + item.ID + "</td ><td>" + item.Adi + "</td><td>" + item.Soyadi + "</td><td>" + item.Sicil + "</td><td><a href='/Kullanicilar/Details/" + item.ID + "'><img width='15' src='../../Content/images/Detay.png'></a></td><td><input id='Kisisec' value='" + item.ID + "' class='KisiSilici' type='image' width='20' src='../../content/images/sil.png' /></td></tr><hr />";
                         });
                         $("#Kisiler").html(row);
                     },
                     error: function (result) {
                         alert("Error");
                     }

                 })
             });
             $(function problem () {
                 $('.KisiSilici').click( function () {
                     var ip = "";
                     $.ajax({
                         url: '@Url.Action("KisilerSil", "tabs")',
                         type: "POST",
                         data: { data: ip },
                         success: function (data) {
                             var row = "<p>" + data + "</p>";
                             $("#CihazKontrol").prepend(row);
                         },
                         error: function (result) {
                             alert("Error");

                         },
                     })
                 });
             });
```

Comment: **$(function problem ()** what does it mean?

Comment: Could you please clearify what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with this code:

- `$(document).ready(...)` is exactly the same as `$(...)`, so using `$(...)` inside `$(document).ready(...)` doesn't make any sense. You could loose `$(...)` wrapping.
- The `problem` name given to anonymous function gives us an error. The function used as arguments are meant to be anonymous or just references (names) to another functions so you can do it like this:

  ```
  $(function() {
      //do smth
  });
  ```

or this:

```
   function do(){
       //do smth
   }
   $(do);
```

So your code, as I see it, should look more like this: (it's hard to tell your point here)

```
        $(document).ready(function Kisilertabs() {
             $("#tabs").tabs();
             var id = @Model.ID.ToString()
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("Kisiler", "Cihazlar")',
                 type: "get",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: { data: id },
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                     var row = "<tr><th width='70'>S. No</th><th width='220'> Adı </th><th width='220'>Soyadı</th><th>Sicil No</th><hr/></tr>";
                     $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                         row += "<tr id='" + item.ID + "'><td>" + item.ID + "</td ><td>" + item.Adi + "</td><td>" + item.Soyadi + "</td><td>" + item.Sicil + "</td><td><a href='/Kullanicilar/Details/" + item.ID + "'><img width='15' src='../../Content/images/Detay.png'></a></td><td><input id='Kisisec' value='" + item.ID + "' class='KisiSilici' type='image' width='20' src='../../content/images/sil.png' /></td></tr><hr />";
                     });
                     $("#Kisiler").html(row);
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert("Error");
                 }

             })
         });

         $('.KisiSilici').click( function () {
             var ip = "";
             $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("KisilerSil", "tabs")',
                 type: "POST",
                 data: { data: ip },
                 success: function (data) {
                     var row = "<p>" + data + "</p>";
                     $("#CihazKontrol").prepend(row);
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert("Error");
                 },
             });
         });
```